# Set and then clear 'click' event function without clearing other events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give focus to one element on the page, bind a click event to that element and after user clicks on it, I need to clear that listener WITHOUT clearing other 'click' events associated with that element.

How do I do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

instead of click, use `one()` function as defined below:

```
$('#element').one('click',function(){...});
```

or for the dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).one('click','#element',function(){...});
```

**[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

Comment: thanks! that's what I need. Perfect shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is not clearing the listener:

```
var clicked = false;

function myEventListener(){
    if(!clicked){
        doStuff();
        clicked = true;
    }
}
```

Sometimes having a flag variable ends up being cleaner than adding and removing event listeners all the time.